# Adding GooglePlayServices support into my Android projects using Eclipse

Tags: android, google-play-services, eclipse-adt

I have installed Google Play Services extras as it says here: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start?hl=en

I can't find out how can I add Google Play Services into my project as it shows here: 
[image]

I don't see any libraries listed in that window because it's empty. I know where that library placed on my HDD. Myabe I can add it manually into my Eclipse project? How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've installed google play services from the sdk manager then import it into your workspace by clicking:

File -> Import -> Existing Android Code -> Browse to this location on your HDD:

Your_AdtBundle_Folder/sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib